# TextView throws designer error displaying string resource

Tags: android, embedded-resource

In working with a new Android project in Eclipse, with the default layout, I discovered a behavior that I'm sure is documented... somewhere... but I cannot identify where.

When the strings.xml "hello" resource contains a string that looks like this:

```
    <string name="hello" 
    formatted="false">@BrandingName: Branding phrase ending with @
    </string>
```

The Eclipse designer throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds resolving a resource value. I presume this is because it doesn't know how to escape some part of "@BrandingName:" correctly? What would be the way to correctly display this using a TextView?

For reference the TextView node looks like this:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting a string resource with "@" will cause errors in the designer. A leading space will prevent that error. The leading space does not appear to be rendered in the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use entity instead of '@' - &#64

And also, if you want to have a formatting for your string, you could use CDATA like this:

```
<string name="hello"><![CDATA[ @BrandingName: Branding phrase ending with @ ]]></string>
```

Comment: <string name="hello" formatted="false">&#64;BrandingName: Branding phrase ending with &#64;</string> yields the same exception. The formulation with CDATA works as long as there is a space before the @. Apparently, starting a string resource with @ attempts to resolve the resource as an indirection...

Comment: +1 for the example that got me close enough to discover the leading-@ bug (at least it looks like a bug)